# SVG JavaScript/ECMAScript API

Tags: javascript, api, svg, cross-browser, ecmascript-5

SVG is ofcourse a XML language, but it's also accessible through JavaScript/ECMAScript. It supports various functions like `getCTM`, `getScreenCTM`, `getBBox`, but I can't find a list anywhere of all the functions that are related to SVG. Or a list that shows which functions are implemented by the various browser vendors. Before I dig into the [source](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/webidl/), I wonder whether someone did that already, or knows a place where I can find a full API reference for SVG.

Comment: [this link](http://caniuse.com/svg-html5) might be useful. Also, if you want a full list of all the functions supported by SVG, you can take a look at the [SVG documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/REC-SVG11-20110816.pdf)...its very lengthy but it should give you all you need.

Comment: The `caniuse` link is only valid for the using the `<svg>` element as inline HTML5. The spec indeed contains all functions that the W3c prescribes but I'm also looking for Gecko/Webkit/Microsoft specific lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG specification has a [DOM chapter](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/svgdom.html) From there you can navigate to the different DOM interfaces e.g. [basic DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#BasicDOMInterfaces).

The Mozilla project is also attempting to [document the SVG DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Gecko_DOM_Reference#SVG_interfaces). It has specifica documentation on many interfaces e.g. [SVGLengthList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Gecko_DOM_Reference#SVG_interfaces) and is trying to document what UAs support which DOM methods but that information is currently rather incomplete. Anyone can add additional information/corrections to the mozilla documentation though.

Microsoft also has a [documentation site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff972117.aspx).

Comment: I misread the W3c spec first, and didn't notice that JavaScript methods were specified, so thank you for that. The Microsoft documentation site was absolutely the thing I needed, but the Mozilla documentation is far from completed, so my question: is there a list of SVG related functions specific that are supported by the various browser vendors is still unanswered. Especially Webkits implementation.

Comment: There is no complete list at this time. The Mozilla site is added to all the time so it will become the reference at some point I imagine, even for Webkit.

Comment: The DOM methods are specified in the SVG spec which has been around for a long time.  Any browser which supports SVG should, in theory, support all of the defined methods.